# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred

Tags: c#, exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll , Additional information: The path is not of a legal form. Error only occurs after it's being pressed for the second time after closing the window .

Heres code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OpenFd = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenFd.Filter = "Images only. |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif;";

        DialogResult dr = OpenFd.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFd.FileName);
        ItemUrl.Text = OpenFd.FileName;


    }
```

Comment: What's the `OpenFd.FileName` on first and second execution?

Comment: Have you debugged through your code?

Comment: @Konrad Kokosa it's the code for browse button as it opens your file to let you choose the photo , OpenFileDest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle whether you selected an image or clicked "Cancel" on the FileDialog. Use this format instead:

```
        OpenFileDialog OpenFd = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenFd.Filter = "Images only. |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif;";

        if (OpenFd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //You selected an image
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFd.FileName);
            ItemUrl.Text = OpenFd.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            //You cancelled the operation
        }
```

Comment: Tried and it work just as fine , I'll see it through thanks

Comment: The exception was probably caused because you closed the dialog without selecting a file, resulting in OpenFd.Filename having an empty string value. When the compiler tried to use it as file address in Image.FromFile() it generated the error

Comment: Yes , Thats what i suspect too , Can i ask if theres any method that , let's say a combobox that has 5 items , And a button , when the combobox is changed to another value the button will not be visible = .Visible=false; What line of code should i use? E.G If combobox1. ???  @innat3

Comment: The comboBox control has an event called SelectedIndexChanged which triggers whenever you change the its value. Inside that event you can set the button's visibility to false (e.g. button1.Visible = false;)

Comment: Oh yes , Cause i was thinking of using a if statement like e.g If combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged , button1.visible=false , As i've already been using It so i guess i'll just add on top , thanks for correcting this for me